# Java EE 6 groups, users and roles -vs- Shiro's roles, users and permissions

Tags: authorization, java-ee-6, shiro

I am trying to mentally map Java EE 6 security concepts of **groups**, **users** and **roles** to the [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)'s concepts of **roles**, **users** and **permissions** and my understanding is that they are incompatible.

Reading through the [Java EE 6 security tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html) it seems that the model is too restrictive: **groups** are configured on a per-server, not per-application, basis which really leaves us with only two flexible concepts to express the authorization mechanism: **users** and **roles**, existing in a simple 1-to-N relationship. In contrast Shiro's model of **roles**, **users** and **permissions** is a lot more dynamic since it enables one to hardcode **permissions** in the annotated code and modify the mapping of **roles** to **permissions** at runtime as things change or as new roles are introduced. I don't see how one can do the same with container-managed authorization as per the Java EE 6 model.

Is my understanding correct? Cause that would imply that one can't really go very far with container-managed authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not compatible and I think that the designers of the Java EE security got it wrong as the terminology seems to be off with regard to ROLES.

From experience I know that providing access control based on ROLE (which is suggested in their documentation) just causes problems down the road when you want to open a capability to other groups/roles.  Permission based access mapped back to roles (or groups) seems to work the best because its a remapping exercise at an abstract level rather than a recode/re-annotate one.

I can see how you'd be confused about the Java EE security model.  I'd suggest taking a closer look at Shiro and how it has modeled application level security.  Les Hazelwood, the creator of Shiro, wrote a [blog about RBAC](http://www.stormpath.com/blog/new-rbac-resource-based-access-control) that makes a lot of sense for applications that need fine grained control even down to the **instance level**.